# How to use B & W video clips as masks for two coloured video clips

Tags: masking

I have three video clips. Below first video of motion graphic with fonts and Gregg shorthand writing, all in black and white.

YouTube: https://youtu.be/AAZr-PiJXGw

Now I want to add colours to black & white video. How do I use black & white details as masks? In other words, how to make black take colours from one coloured video and white, those from another?

[image]

Comment: Add a "Mask" strip modifier to your upper colored strip.  As the input for your mask modifier, choose the b&w writing strip.  Set the "Blend" of your upper colored strip to "Alpha Over".   To invert things, invert the colors of the mask or change the stacking of your color strips.

Comment: @risingfall. No matter how late my response, thank you very much. I had experimented with nodes and gained satisfactory results. For remembering node trees for future usages, I keep them in scrapbooks. I have your suggested nodes on page 13. Thanks for suggesting nodes. 
 https://docs.google.com/presentation/d/1E0PznImialXmQZTk-22ZLSMGOOrl-L5ycSu9sCktYPI/mobilepresent?slide=id.g2ea278815baf8f92_0